# Error using PHP_Depend and PHP_PMD

Tags: sonarqube, pmd, pdepend

I have a problem using php Depend and PMD. When I use:

```
pdepend --summary-xml=/home/<mydirectory>/.sonar/pdepend.xml --suffix=php,php3,php4,php5,phtml,inc /home/<mydirectory>
```

this is the result:

> Parsing...
>   ..................................................  1260
>   ........................PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to PHP_Depend_Parser_UnexpectedTokenException::__construct() must be an instance of PHP_Depend_Token, integer given, called in /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php on line 5444 and defined in /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser/UnexpectedTokenException.php on line 70
>   PHP Stack trace:
>       PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/pdepend:0
>       PHP   2. PHP_Depend_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/pdepend:78
>       PHP   3. PHP_Depend_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/TextUI/Command.php:679
>       PHP   4. PHP_Depend_TextUI_Runner->run() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/TextUI/Command.php:206
>       PHP   5. PHP_Depend->analyze() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/TextUI/Runner.php:331
>       PHP   6. PHP_Depend->performParseProcess() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend.php:306
>       PHP   7. PHP_Depend_Parser->parse() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend.php:560
>       PHP   8. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseOptionalStatement() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:370
>       PHP   9. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseIfStatement() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:5474
>       PHP  10. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseStatementBody() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:3195
>       PHP  11. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseStatement() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:2320
>       PHP  12. PHP_Depend_Parser_UnexpectedTokenException->__construct() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:5444

The same happens with:

```
phpmd /home/<mydirectory> xml /home/<mydirectory>/Sonar_Way_php.xml
```

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to  PHP_Depend_Parser_UnexpectedTokenException::__construct() must be an instance of PHP_Depend_Token, integer given, called in /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php on line 5444 and defined in /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser/UnexpectedTokenException.php on line 70
>   PHP Stack trace:

```
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpmd:0
PHP   2. PHP_PMD_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpmd:48
PHP   3. PHP_PMD_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHP/PMD/TextUI/Command.php:151
PHP   4. PHP_PMD->processFiles() /usr/share/php/PHP/PMD/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   5. PHP_PMD_Parser->parse() /usr/share/php/PHP/PMD.php:203
PHP   6. PHP_Depend->analyze() /usr/share/php/PHP/PMD/Parser.php:128
PHP   7. PHP_Depend->performParseProcess() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend.php:306
PHP   8. PHP_Depend_Parser->parse() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend.php:560
PHP   9. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseOptionalStatement() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:370
PHP  10. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseIfStatement() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:5474
PHP  11. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseStatementBody() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:3195
PHP  12. PHP_Depend_Parser->parseStatement() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:2320
PHP  13. PHP_Depend_Parser_UnexpectedTokenException->__construct() /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php:5444
```

¿Any sugestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of pdepend and pmd. In /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/parser.php I changed:

```
private function parseStatement()
{
    if (null === ($stmt = $this->parseOptionalStatement())) {
        throw new PHP_Depend_Parser_UnexpectedTokenException(
            $this->tokenizer->next(),
            $this->sourceFile->getFileName()
        );
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```

for this:

```
private function parseStatement()
{
    if (null === ($stmt = $this->parseOptionalStatement())) {
        throw new PHP_Depend_Parser_UnexpectedTokenException(
            new PHP_Depend_Token,
            $this->sourceFile->getFileName()
        );
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```

I obtain only warnings and the process continue:

PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for PHP_Depend_Token::__construct(), called in /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Parser.php on line 5442 and defined in /usr/share/php/PHP/Depend/Token.php on line 121

We can wait next upgrade ;)